# Thanos Receiver not deleting old data in Persistent Volume (PV) after retention is exceeded

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, thanos

I have set up Kube Prometheus Stack with Thanos on my Kubernetes cluster, and I'm using the Thanos Receiver instead of the sidecar approach. I have also configured the Thanos Compactor and Minio for offloading data. Here are some key details of my setup:

- Prometheus retention is set to 2 hours.
- Thanos Receiver retention is set to 6 hours.
- Using Longhorn PV as the persistence volume for the Thanos Receiver.
- Data is successfully offloaded to Minio storage.

My issue is that, even though I have configured the retention settings for both Prometheus and the Thanos Receiver, the **Receiver doesn't seem to automatically delete old data from the Longhorn PV** when the retention period is exceeded. As a result, my PV is filling up with old data, and I need a way to ensure that old data is deleted as per the configured retention.

I'm wondering if there's a specific configuration or step that I might be missing to enable automatic data deletion from the PV when the retention period is exceeded.